# Sass map that contains a function

Tags: angular, sass

I have a Sass map that I use to hold styles for headers. I loop through the map and use the key:value pairs for the css rules. I want to use a function to convert pixels to rem units. When the mixin runs for the header the function isn't evaluated.

**Sass map**

```
$headers: (
    alpha: (
        font-size: get-relative-font-size(36px, $font-size-base, ''),
        font-weight: 700,
        color: $ra-color-black,
    ),
    beta: (
        font-size: 24px,
        font-weight: 500,
        color: $ra-color-black,
    ),
);
```

**Mixin**

```
@mixin getHeader($header) {
    @if (map-has-key($headers, $header)) {
        $styles: map-get($headers, $header);
        @each $property, $value in $styles {
            #{$property}: $value;
        }
    } @else {
        @warn 'No styles found for #{$header} header';
    }
}
```

**Function**

```
@function get-relative-font-size($actual, $relative: $font-size-base, $unitType: 'rem') {
    @if $unitType == 'rem' {
        @return #{($actual / $font-size-base)}rem;
    } @else {
        @return ceil(percentage($actual / $relative));
    }
}
```

Here is the output in the browser.

```
font-size: get-relative-font-size(36px, 16px, "");
font-weight: 700;
color: #000;
```

What's weird is if I put the code into Sassmeister it works as expected, https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/df18795eaec5737d61e13b435e841cd0

This is for an angular-cli (v1.5.0) project. I see node-sass v4.6.0 being used.

Comment: Why do you store styles for element into sass maps? It seems like feature for the feature. It would be better to use %placeholders if you want to use the same styles for several elements.

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Placeholder_Selectors___foo

Comment: Mixins vs Extends https://tech.bellycard.com/blog/sass-mixins-vs-extends-the-data/

Comment: The idea is that mixin contains its own styles. And have several params to customize mixin output. In my opinion you don't have any benefits of using maps for styles. You should duplicate all properties every time you create new type of header. Maybe this example would be useful for you https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e67f2f4399f11c09cc92b1fd4d54364e